# Turn table including appendix title

Tags: tables, rotating, landscape

The following code is my table. I want to turn this table including the appendix section title 90 degrees clockwise. I know `\begin{landscape}` can do this but it only turns it 90 degrees counter clockwise. Also, I want to be able to shift the table manually (by for example `\hskip`, like I did in the code below) on the rotated page. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

\newpage
\section{VIF Tests Postcode Level Data Set}\label{appendix D}
\begin{table}[H]
\small
\centering
\hskip-2cm\begin{tabular}{l|llllllllllllll}\hline
       \textit{Table} & \textbf{Houses}     & \textbf{Single}     & \textbf{Food/}   & \textbf{Own/}   & \textbf{Married/}    & \textbf{Two-}   & \textbf{Three-}    & \textbf{Five-}   & \textbf{Four-}    & \textbf{Dutch/}   & \textbf{Men/}  & \textbf{Age}  & \textbf{Houses} & \textbf{Houses}    \\
      \textit{4:} & \textbf{before} & \textbf{Adult} & \textbf{Non-Food} & \textbf{Rent} & \textbf{Non-} & \textbf{Person} & \textbf{Person} & \textbf{or-more} & \textbf{Person} & \textbf{Foreign} & \textbf{Women} & \textbf{$<$ 65/} & \textbf{’60-’69} & \textbf{’70-’79}
      \\
      \textit{VIF} & \textbf{'59}  & \textbf{$<$ 65} & \textbf{Ratio} & \textbf{Ratio} & \textbf{Married} & \textbf{House-} & \textbf{House-} & \textbf{-Person} & \textbf{House-} & \textbf{Ratio} &  \textbf{Ratio} & \textbf{Age} 
      \\
      \textit{Tests} & &\textbf{House-} &&& \textbf{Ratio}  & \textbf{holds} & \textbf{holds} & \textbf{House-} & \textbf{holds} &&& \textbf{$\geq$ 65}
      \\
      && \textbf{holds}&&&&&&\textbf{holds}&&&& \textbf{Ratio}
      \\
      \hline \hline
\textbf{VIF1}  & 12.75  & 28.55  & 1.56 & 2.23 & 12.14 & 4.40 & 7.03  & 3.16 & 16.19 & 3.02  & 1.80 & 4.61 & 7.96   & 3.46   \\
\textbf{VIF2}  & 144.80 & 179.48 & 2.83 & 4.13 & 29.01 & 9.46 & 13.47 & 6.02 & 32.65 & 13.55 & 3.45 & 8.05 & \textcolor{red}{234.14} & 48.04  \\
\textbf{VIF3}  & 15.91  & 36.21  & 2.82 & 4.09 & 28.71 & 9.41 & 12.22 & 5.76 & 26.98 & 13.44 & 3.28 & 7.87 &        & 7.75   \\
\textbf{VIF4}  & 15.76  & \textcolor{red}{36.19}  & 2.69 & 3.74 & 28.70 & 9.41 & 12.20 & 5.75 & 26.96 & 13.44 & 3.28 & 7.74 &        & 7.75   \\
\textbf{VIF5}  & 9.13   &        & 2.69 & 3.72 & \textcolor{red}{27.89} & 9.12 & 11.62 & 5.75 & 24.43 & 12.24 & 3.24 & 6.94 &        & 6.58   \\
\textbf{VIF6}  & 8.93   &        & 2.69 & 3.28 &       & 6.14 & 11.62 & 5.71 & 18.81 & 12.20 & 3.23 & 6.49 &        & 6.06   \\
\textbf{VIF7}  & 8.84   &        & 2.68 & 3.28 &       & 6.08 & 11.61 & 5.65 & \textcolor{red}{18.25} & 12.15 & 3.23 & 6.26 &        & 5.87   \\
\textbf{VIF8}  & 8.84   &        & 2.68 & 3.25 &       & 5.32 & 8.15  & 5.41 &       & 10.47 & 3.22 & 6.26 &        & 5.86   \\
\textbf{VIF9}  & 6.19   &        & 2.33 & 2.91 &       & 3.66 & 6.93  & 4.50 &       & 8.79  & 2.48 & 5.89 &        & 5.62   \\
\textbf{VIF10} & 6.15   &        & 2.33 & 2.88 &       & 3.48 & 6.36  & 4.50 &       & 8.67  & 2.26 & 5.89 &        & 3.69   \\
\textbf{VIF11} & 4.84   &        & 1.99 & 2.73 &       & 3.35 & 6.22  & 4.49 &       & 7.57  & 2.06 & 5.72 &        & 3.53  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.stack...

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear, what you after. The following solution rotate table on the way as you show in image in comment (if I understood it correct, you like to have section titles and top of table at left page border, what is by the way *is at odds with the intuitive layout*).

Use `\hskip-2cm` to shift table is not good idea. Better is to change geometry of this page (by use of `newgeometry` from `geometry` package or by use `\changetext` defined in the `changetext` package. However, with proposed redesign (see MWE below)  this shift or increasing text area size is not needed anymore.

Off-topics remarks:

- Due to wide column headers your table is wider (using even `\footnotesize` font size)  that can be fit on page (this you try compensate with `\hskip=-2cm`, isn't it?).
- Column headers can become narrower if you rotate them, for example by `\rothed` command defined in the `makecell` package
- numbers in table is easier compare if they are aligned at decimal points. For this is handy `S` column type defined in the `siunitx` package.
- Use of `S` columns enables simple annotate some numbers in the table by help of `etoolbox` package.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[figuresleft]
            {rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}% for annotate numbers
                \bfseries\color{red}}                          %

\begin{document}
    \setcounter{page}{77}
    \begin{sidewaystable*}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Own/Rent Ratio}
    \sisetup{detect-weight,
             mode=text}
\section{VIF Tests Postcode Level Data Set}
\label{appendix D}
%
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} >{\bfseries}l 
                                *{2}{S[table-format=3.2] }
                                *{2}{S[table-format=1.2] }
                                *{2}{S[table-format=2.2]S[table-format=1.2]}
                                *{3}{S[table-format=2.2]}     
                                      S[table-format=1.2]
                                      S[table-format=3.2]
                                      S[table-format=2.2]}
   \toprule
\normalfont\itshape
\makecell{Table 4:\\
          VIF Tests}
        & {\rothead{Houses before 1959}}
            & {\rothead{Single Adult\\ $<65$ Households}}
                & {\rothead{Food/Non-Food Ratio}}
                    & {\rothead{Own/Rent Ratio}}
                        & {\rothead{Married/Non Married Ratio}}
                            & {\rothead{Two-Person Households}}
                                & {\rothead{Three-Person Households}}
        & {\rothead{Five-Person Households}}
            & {\rothead{Four-Person Households}}
                & {\rothead{Dutch/Foreign Ratio}}
                    & {\rothead{Men/Women Ratio}}
                        & {\rothead{Age $<65$\\ Age $\geq 65$}}
                            & {\rothead{Houses 1960-1969}}
                                & {\rothead{Houses 1970-1999}}                  \\
      \midrule
VIF1    & 12.75     & 28.55     & 1.56  & 2.23  & 12.14     & 4.40      & 7.03  
        & 3.16      & 16.19     & 3.02  & 1.80  & 4.61      & 7.96      & 3.46  \\ 
VIF2    & 144.80    & 179.48    & 2.83  & 4.13  & 29.01     & 9.46      & 13.47 
        & 6.02      & 32.65     & 13.55 & 3.45  & 8.05      &\B 234.14  & 48.04 \\
VIF3    & 15.91     & 36.21     & 2.82  & 4.09  & 28.71     & 9.41      & 12.22 
        & 5.76      & 26.98     & 13.44 & 3.28  & 7.87      &           & 7.75  \\
VIF4    & 15.76     &\B 36.19   & 2.69  & 3.74  & 28.70     & 9.41      & 12.20 
        & 5.75      & 26.96     & 13.44 & 3.28  & 7.74      &           & 7.75  \\
VIF5    & 9.13      &           & 2.69  & 3.72  &\B 27.89   & 9.12      & 11.62 
        & 5.75      & 24.43     & 12.24 & 3.24  & 6.94      &           & 6.58  \\
VIF6    & 8.93      &           & 2.69  & 3.28  &           & 6.14      & 11.62
        & 5.71      & 18.81     & 12.20 & 3.23  & 6.49      &           & 6.06  \\
VIF7    & 8.84      &           & 2.68  & 3.28  &           & 6.08      & 11.61 
        & 5.65      &\B 18.25   & 12.15 & 3.23  & 6.26      &           & 5.87  \\
VIF8    & 8.84      &           & 2.68  & 3.25  &           & 5.32      & 8.15  
        & 5.41      &           & 10.47 & 3.22  & 6.26      &           & 5.86  \\ 
VIF9    & 6.19      &           & 2.33  & 2.91  &           & 3.66      & 6.93  
        & 4.50      &           & 8.79  & 2.48  & 5.89      &           & 5.62  \\
VIF10   & 6.15      &           & 2.33  & 2.88  &           & 3.48      & 6.36  
        & 4.50      &           & 8.67  & 2.26  & 5.89      &           & 3.69  \\
VIF11   & 4.84      &           & 1.99  & 2.73  &           & 3.35      & 6.22  
        & 4.49      &           & 7.57  & 2.06  & 5.72      &           & 3.53  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \end{sidewaystable*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*: I rather would counterclock rotate table as it is default settings for `rotating` as well for `lscape` or `pdflscape` packages.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{float,xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\section{VIF Tests Postcode Level Data Set\label{appendix D}}
\small
\centering
\hskip-12cm\begin{tabular}{l|llllllllllllll}\hline
       \textit{Table} & \textbf{Houses}     & \textbf{Single}     & \textbf{Food/}   & \textbf{Own/}   & \textbf{Married/}    & \textbf{Two-}   & \textbf{Three-}    & \textbf{Five-}   & \textbf{Four-}    & \textbf{Dutch/}   & \textbf{Men/}  & \textbf{Age}  & \textbf{Houses} & \textbf{Houses}    \\
      \textit{4:} & \textbf{before} & \textbf{Adult} & \textbf{Non-Food} & \textbf{Rent} & \textbf{Non-} & \textbf{Person} & \textbf{Person} & \textbf{or-more} & \textbf{Person} & \textbf{Foreign} & \textbf{Women} & \textbf{$<$ 65/} & \textbf{’60-’69} & \textbf{’70-’79}
      \\
      \textit{VIF} & \textbf{'59}  & \textbf{$<$ 65} & \textbf{Ratio} & \textbf{Ratio} & \textbf{Married} & \textbf{House-} & \textbf{House-} & \textbf{-Person} & \textbf{House-} & \textbf{Ratio} &  \textbf{Ratio} & \textbf{Age} 
      \\
      \textit{Tests} & &\textbf{House-} &&& \textbf{Ratio}  & \textbf{holds} & \textbf{holds} & \textbf{House-} & \textbf{holds} &&& \textbf{$\geq$ 65}
      \\
      && \textbf{holds}&&&&&&\textbf{holds}&&&& \textbf{Ratio}
      \\
      \hline \hline
\textbf{VIF1}  & 12.75  & 28.55  & 1.56 & 2.23 & 12.14 & 4.40 & 7.03  & 3.16 & 16.19 & 3.02  & 1.80 & 4.61 & 7.96   & 3.46   \\
\textbf{VIF2}  & 144.80 & 179.48 & 2.83 & 4.13 & 29.01 & 9.46 & 13.47 & 6.02 & 32.65 & 13.55 & 3.45 & 8.05 & \textcolor{red}{234.14} & 48.04  \\
\textbf{VIF3}  & 15.91  & 36.21  & 2.82 & 4.09 & 28.71 & 9.41 & 12.22 & 5.76 & 26.98 & 13.44 & 3.28 & 7.87 &        & 7.75   \\
\textbf{VIF4}  & 15.76  & \textcolor{red}{36.19}  & 2.69 & 3.74 & 28.70 & 9.41 & 12.20 & 5.75 & 26.96 & 13.44 & 3.28 & 7.74 &        & 7.75   \\
\textbf{VIF5}  & 9.13   &        & 2.69 & 3.72 & \textcolor{red}{27.89} & 9.12 & 11.62 & 5.75 & 24.43 & 12.24 & 3.24 & 6.94 &        & 6.58   \\
\textbf{VIF6}  & 8.93   &        & 2.69 & 3.28 &       & 6.14 & 11.62 & 5.71 & 18.81 & 12.20 & 3.23 & 6.49 &        & 6.06   \\
\textbf{VIF7}  & 8.84   &        & 2.68 & 3.28 &       & 6.08 & 11.61 & 5.65 & \textcolor{red}{18.25} & 12.15 & 3.23 & 6.26 &        & 5.87   \\
\textbf{VIF8}  & 8.84   &        & 2.68 & 3.25 &       & 5.32 & 8.15  & 5.41 &       & 10.47 & 3.22 & 6.26 &        & 5.86   \\
\textbf{VIF9}  & 6.19   &        & 2.33 & 2.91 &       & 3.66 & 6.93  & 4.50 &       & 8.79  & 2.48 & 5.89 &        & 5.62   \\
\textbf{VIF10} & 6.15   &        & 2.33 & 2.88 &       & 3.48 & 6.36  & 4.50 &       & 8.67  & 2.26 & 5.89 &        & 3.69   \\
\textbf{VIF11} & 4.84   &        & 1.99 & 2.73 &       & 3.35 & 6.22  & 4.49 &       & 7.57  & 2.06 & 5.72 &        & 3.53  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\clearpage

\begin{sidewaystable}
\section{VIF Tests Postcode Level Data Set\label{appendix D}}
\small
\centering
\hskip-12cm\begin{tabular}{l|llllllllllllll}\hline
       \textit{Table} & \textbf{Houses}     & \textbf{Single}     & \textbf{Food/}   & \textbf{Own/}   & \textbf{Married/}    & \textbf{Two-}   & \textbf{Three-}    & \textbf{Five-}   & \textbf{Four-}    & \textbf{Dutch/}   & \textbf{Men/}  & \textbf{Age}  & \textbf{Houses} & \textbf{Houses}    \\
      \textit{4:} & \textbf{before} & \textbf{Adult} & \textbf{Non-Food} & \textbf{Rent} & \textbf{Non-} & \textbf{Person} & \textbf{Person} & \textbf{or-more} & \textbf{Person} & \textbf{Foreign} & \textbf{Women} & \textbf{$<$ 65/} & \textbf{’60-’69} & \textbf{’70-’79}
      \\
      \textit{VIF} & \textbf{'59}  & \textbf{$<$ 65} & \textbf{Ratio} & \textbf{Ratio} & \textbf{Married} & \textbf{House-} & \textbf{House-} & \textbf{-Person} & \textbf{House-} & \textbf{Ratio} &  \textbf{Ratio} & \textbf{Age} 
      \\
      \textit{Tests} & &\textbf{House-} &&& \textbf{Ratio}  & \textbf{holds} & \textbf{holds} & \textbf{House-} & \textbf{holds} &&& \textbf{$\geq$ 65}
      \\
      && \textbf{holds}&&&&&&\textbf{holds}&&&& \textbf{Ratio}
      \\
      \hline \hline
\textbf{VIF1}  & 12.75  & 28.55  & 1.56 & 2.23 & 12.14 & 4.40 & 7.03  & 3.16 & 16.19 & 3.02  & 1.80 & 4.61 & 7.96   & 3.46   \\
\textbf{VIF2}  & 144.80 & 179.48 & 2.83 & 4.13 & 29.01 & 9.46 & 13.47 & 6.02 & 32.65 & 13.55 & 3.45 & 8.05 & \textcolor{red}{234.14} & 48.04  \\
\textbf{VIF3}  & 15.91  & 36.21  & 2.82 & 4.09 & 28.71 & 9.41 & 12.22 & 5.76 & 26.98 & 13.44 & 3.28 & 7.87 &        & 7.75   \\
\textbf{VIF4}  & 15.76  & \textcolor{red}{36.19}  & 2.69 & 3.74 & 28.70 & 9.41 & 12.20 & 5.75 & 26.96 & 13.44 & 3.28 & 7.74 &        & 7.75   \\
\textbf{VIF5}  & 9.13   &        & 2.69 & 3.72 & \textcolor{red}{27.89} & 9.12 & 11.62 & 5.75 & 24.43 & 12.24 & 3.24 & 6.94 &        & 6.58   \\
\textbf{VIF6}  & 8.93   &        & 2.69 & 3.28 &       & 6.14 & 11.62 & 5.71 & 18.81 & 12.20 & 3.23 & 6.49 &        & 6.06   \\
\textbf{VIF7}  & 8.84   &        & 2.68 & 3.28 &       & 6.08 & 11.61 & 5.65 & \textcolor{red}{18.25} & 12.15 & 3.23 & 6.26 &        & 5.87   \\
\textbf{VIF8}  & 8.84   &        & 2.68 & 3.25 &       & 5.32 & 8.15  & 5.41 &       & 10.47 & 3.22 & 6.26 &        & 5.86   \\
\textbf{VIF9}  & 6.19   &        & 2.33 & 2.91 &       & 3.66 & 6.93  & 4.50 &       & 8.79  & 2.48 & 5.89 &        & 5.62   \\
\textbf{VIF10} & 6.15   &        & 2.33 & 2.88 &       & 3.48 & 6.36  & 4.50 &       & 8.67  & 2.26 & 5.89 &        & 3.69   \\
\textbf{VIF11} & 4.84   &        & 1.99 & 2.73 &       & 3.35 & 6.22  & 4.49 &       & 7.57  & 2.06 & 5.72 &        & 3.53  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your assumption is true. I added it. This solution however turns the table and section title 90 degrees counter clockwise while I want it to turn 90 degrees clockwise. Also, ```\hskip``` does not work anymore as it used to be in my example.

Comment: Have edited the answer, please check and confirm...

Comment: The shifting of the table works, but the table is still rotated 90 degrees counter clockwise and not 90 degrees clockwise as I would like to have.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot or an image of your table rotation requirement?

Comment: This is what I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p82QM.png

Comment: Just remove the option "figuresleft" from the "rotating" package for this requirement. Please check with the edited answer...

Comment: Still it does not show the correctly rotated table